# How to overload magento CartController

Tags: magento, controller, overloading, cart

Im trying to overload my CartCotroller so create folder structure like my CartController in the local:

```
app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
```

My question is, does magento execute this Controller and ignore the one whose in the core?
Cause what im trying to do is, i want to add an condition when the customer post a coupon code without changing my form method value. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Magento will execute the controller placed in app/code/local instead of the core file. An even better way to implement new code or extend the core is to create your own module. So you'd have all your custom code in one place and it's maintanable should you update Magento.
Smashing Magazine gives a nice basic roundup on how to accomplish this. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

Comment: hmm.. i already try to do it that way but still magento executing the one whose in the core. my guess is maybe because i was submitting my form to the core not in the local, but like what you said magento should execute the local one so what do you think is the problem in here?

Comment: Have you made sure that you are trying to overwrite the right function? You could copy your code from local to the core file to test wheter it's executed from there. If not, you're probably extending/ overwriting the wrong controller or function. And you can try deleting all files in var/cache/.